# CSS alignment issue in different screen resolution

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a header containing an image and search box. Both header area and results area are separate `divs` .

Search box is in header area. In left side of results div there are some menu items. I need to align my search box with results start area.

In `.tk-bl-header` I have added margin-left=5em to work. But when I move to different screen resolution it gets misaligned.

```css
       .tk-bl-header .tk-header-search-area {

         display: inline-block;

         float: left;

         width: 43.75%;

         padding-left: 1.5625%;

         padding-right: 1.5625%;

         position: relative;

         color: black;

         margin-left: 5em;

       }

       .searchform-container .searchform {

         margin-bottom: 1em;

       }

       header .tk-bl-header h1 #logo a {

         text-decoration: none;

       }

       a.library-logo {

         background: url("../abc.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;

         width: 110px;

         height: 100px;

       }

       a.logo-name {

         margin-top: 10px;

         font-size: 20px;

       }

       div#second-header {

         display: inline-block;

         height: 65px;

         position: relative;

         width: 100%;

         /* overflow: hidden; */

       }
```

```html
<header class="tk-bl-header">

<div id="second-header">
  <h1 id="logo">
  <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" class="library-logo"></a> 
        <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}" class="logo-name">ABCD</a>
 </h1>

  <div class="tk-header-search-area">
    <div class="tk-header-search-form">
      <div class="searchform-container ">
        <form id="" class="searchform" action="" method="get" data-filters="">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Search</legend>
            <input type="text" name="q" class="query" value='${query.value.display}' placeholder="Search documents.." autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" required>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search">
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="col-right-top" class="sidebar col"></div>

</div>



</header>
```

Comment: There is no element with a `tk-bl-header` class in your HTML, is it normal?

Comment: if you have then please provide the url of website.

Comment: Actually this div is wrapped inside header tag with tk-bl-header class